# 2015 Santa Fe Sport, rear "LH" shell hanging off?

Tags: hyundai, santa-fe

my wife noticed upon arriving home the other day that a portion of some kind of plastic shell on the driver side rear of the vehicle was hanging down. I got under the car and snapped a few photos, I can definitely see there appears to be missing bolts/fasteners of some kind but I'm not sure what this part is or what needs repairing. Is it the whole body cover, a few fasteners, both or neither? Help appreciated! (I've duct taped it up a bit so it's not hanging down.)

I've tried to outline the area as best I can with these photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a non-structural plastic panel that improves aerodynamics and mpg and prevents water, mud, sand and salt from gunking up the hollow area that it covers. Assuming that the 2012 and 2015 models are basically the same back there except for cosmetic differences, you'll find a wiring harness for trailer lights inside the cover.

Those fasteners don't really screw in, they push in. You loosen them by turning the cross-hole counterclockwise with a Phillips screwdriver until the head moves slightly away from the body of the fastener, then use a body trim tool to retract the core as far as it will go. Once the core is retracted, the fastener can be wiggled out of the hole.

You may need replacement fasteners if those are no longer holding.

There's no harm in leaving the duct tape on for a few days until you have time to do a proper repair.

Comment: Thank you! The part that seems to keep slipping off isn’t the push in screws but little holes that (I think) are supposed to be pushed over screw threads and affix the part to the car. You can’t really see that from the photos, you have to be directly under the vehicle looking up. Maybe the plastic “teeth” around the holes lost their grip? @MTA

Comment: @MattKoch Maybe. Perhaps you can find plastic washers of just the right size to grip the fasteners better. Or take the fasteners to an auto parts store to see if you can find a fastener with a slightly larger outside diameter to grip the existing holes better.